# How to make my background image full screen?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm doing a project in python django and trying to make my background full screen.

The html code:

```
{

% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Colorlib Templates">
    <meta name="author" content="Colorlib">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Colorlib Templates">

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Au Register Forms by Colorlib</title>

    <!-- Icons font CSS-->
    <link href="{% static 'register/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="{% static 'register/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="{% static 'register/vendor/select2/select2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="{% static 'register/vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="{% static 'register/css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" >
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('{% static "webmonitor/images/bg-01.jpg" %}')  ;" >
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-65 p-b-54">
            <form method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
                    Login
                </span>
                <form method="post" >
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-23" data-validate = "Username is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type your username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf206;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Type your password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-symbol="&#xf190;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31">
                        <a href="#">
                            
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <button class="login100-form-btn">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The css code:   /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ RESTYLE TAG ]*/

```
* {
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Poppins-Regular, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
a {
    font-family: Poppins-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  color: #a64bf4;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin: 0px;
}

p {
    font-family: Poppins-Regular;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
button {
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
    border: none !important;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Utility ]*/
.txt1 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #666666;
}

.txt2 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bg1 {background-color: #3b5998}
.bg2 {background-color: #1da1f2}
.bg3 {background-color: #ea4335}



/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ login ]*/
.limiter {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-login100 {
  width: 100%;  
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}


.wrap-login100 {
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Form ]*/

.login100-form {
  width: 100%;
}

.login100-form-title {
  display: block;
  font-family: Poppins-Bold;
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Input ]*/

.wrap-input100 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.label-input100 {
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.input100 {
  font-family: Poppins-Medium;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;

  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 7px 0 43px;
}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: I've included my entire css code as requested. Sorry if it is too much. I'm not sure where the error is

Comment: Try with background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: @Akib hi sorry but this did not work :/

Comment: Share the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

try this once

```
html {
  background: url(img_man.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

remove `position : center` and try

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply but it didnt work :/

Comment: hello! @meister . please check  .html properly once, that have you used classes of login mentioned in .css

Comment: one more idea I got just try . remove that image from block(make only form ) , and directly apply it in ```body{}```
so that form and background will be separate element. (just try )

Answer (score 0):

Css for container-login100 is correct, maybe there is something wrong in the parent container. For example you can have margin, padding, or other instruction that prevents the container-login100 to expand itself and grow to cover all the free space. Maybe is better if you post parent code and style

Comment: hi thanks for your help! i've updated my code in the question

Comment: good, but seems that html doesn't match your screenshot, you posted registration form, you are looking to fix login form, so in your html doesn't exist the class container-login100

Comment: hi sorry i have corrected the code!

Comment: Your login is inside `container` class, maybe in the container something prevent your div to go 100%. Try to remove container e leave only limiter. After that try to set limiter:

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```